# Main content background full width

Tags: html, css

I have some issue with `.main` background. I'm trying to get full width of background but I can't. I've looked some similar questions about this but I couldn't fix my issue. Here's my code. Here's my fonts so you can see better my point. [Fonts](http://jmp.sh/b/rBE9IcSDdMGtWjaiwhkB)

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>MaxSkins-Home</title>
  
<style type="text/css">
  
  body {
   background-color: white;    
   background-attachment: fixed;              
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   min-width: 1000px;
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Jocker";
   src: url("JockeyOne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   src: url("PacificaCondensed-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); 
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   src:url("ReklameScript.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  h1 {
   font-size: 120px;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   margin-left: 45;
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }  

  h2 {
   font-size: 70;
   margin-left: 224;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }

  #header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: auto;
 
  }
  
  #navigacija {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 50px;  
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: right;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #089DE3;
   z-index: 9999;   
  }
  
  #navigacija a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 50px; 
   font-size: 30px; 
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
 
  #navigacija a:hover {
   background: #00C5CD;
  }
  
  .main1 {
   margin-top: 50px;
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   font-size: 50;
   background: #089DE3;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 194;
  }
  
  .video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 0px;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   bottom: 930;
   right: 0px;
  }
  .video-container iframe,  
  .video-container object,  
  .video-container embed {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  .video-wrapper {
   width: 640px;
   float: right;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>  
  

  </head>

<body>
 <div id="header">
 <div id="navigacija">
       <a href="Home.html"><b>HOME</b></a> 
       <a href="Shop.html"><b>SHOP</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>GET POINTS</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>INFO</b></a> 
     
   </div>
 </div>


  <h1><b>EARN POINTS,<br> GET SKINS!</b></h1>
  <h2><b>How does it work?</b></h2>
 <div class="main1">
  <p><b>It's simple!<br> Watch videos, do tasks and have fun!<br>After earning large amount of coins,<br> contact us to get your skins!<b></p>
 
 </div>

 <div class="video-wrapper">
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lwItL2NXwDw" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <!-- /video -->
</div>
<!-- /video-wrapper --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Already done that.

Comment: "I'm trying to get full width of background but I can't." What do you mean by this, what's wrong?

Comment: `.main1` has a full-width background for me.

Comment: Ah, I se @user6003859 fixed the CSS you posted. Looks like the blue background goes full width now that the body styles are being applied?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that the invalid `<style>` tags were part of the problem. I just thought that it was an accident while copying the problem to SO.

Comment: @MichaelCoker user6003859 Yeah my CSS was in HTML... So I've just separated those two and same thing... user6003859 Try downloading those fonts. 'Cuz when i try to open my site from snippets it seems that background is full width but try copy and paste my code in let's say Notepad and save it. You will see that its different.

Comment: What is a _contect_?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem was some invalid CSS. You had a `<style></style>` tag in your CSS, but that is only needed when the CSS is inside your mark-up (HTML).

I removed the HTML tag from your CSS, and - at least for me - `.main1` has a full-width background now. *I'm assuming that was your problem..?*

Comment: Yeah, my CSS is in HTML. I'm gonna try creating css file separated and see what happens.